# Share authentication cookie across subdomains in ASP.NET Core - cannot login

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

I am trying to implement sharing authentication cookie across two subdomains in ASP.NET Core web apps. I have changed Startup.cs and added following code in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("{{my_url_to_blob_storage}}"))
                .SetApplicationName("myapp");

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "myapp";
            options.Cookie.Domain = ".azurewebsites.net";
        });
```

I have published the web app to Azure, but when trying HttpContext.SignInAsync(), nothing happens - HttpContext.User is not set.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! When using custom domain, everything runs as expected

Comment: Can you share the code of your Startup class? Is it the same code for both sites?